# DWARF diff tool for debug info file

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb, g++

I have a binary that is 10s of MB large without debugging symbols, but with debugging symbols its 100s of MB large.  In the normal development cycle I copy the several 100 MB binary (with debug symbols) over a very slow link repeatedly.  I am trying to minimize the amount of information I need to send to speed up the transfer.

I have researched binary diff tools like [bsdiff](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/bsdiff.1.html) and [courgette](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette), but the time and memory they take is prohibitive for me given the size of the binary and the frequency I'd like to be able to transfer it.  As pointed out in responses, there are ways to mitigate the problem of needing to send the debug info to the remote host.  `gdbserver` won't work in my use case because we'd also like the application to be able to log backtrace information with symbols.  Using `PC` values and `addr2line` was considered, but keeping the source binary around can be confusing if trying to make forward progress while also testing on a remote machine.  Additionally, with multiple developers, having access to debug info on some other developer's machine isn't always easy.

`strip` can separate out the binary from the debug info, so I was wondering if there were tools to compare and "diff" two debug info files, since that's where 95% of my space is anyway?  And between iterations, a lot of the raw content in the debug info file is the same (i.e. the names and relationships, which is painfully verbose in C++).

Using the suggestion from user657267 I have also investigated using `-gsplit-dwarf` to separate out the `.dwo` files.  This may work, but my concern is that over time core headers will change and cause minor changes to every `.dwo` file, so I'll end up transferring everything anyway assuming my "base" stays the same, even though most of the content of the `.dwo` file is unchanged.  This could possibly be worked around in interesting ways (e.g. repository of `.dwo` files), but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

*So, assuming I have a DWARF debug info file from a previous compilation, is there a way to compare it to the DWARF debug info file from the current compilation and get something smaller to transfer?*

As an absolute last resort, I can write some type of lookup and translation code.  But are there convenient tools for viewing, modifying, and then "unmodifying" a DWARF debug info file?  I have found tools like [pyelftools](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/06/pyelftools-python-library-for-parsing-elf-and-dwarf/) and [DWARF utilities](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/dwarves/).  The former only reads the DIEs, and too slowly in my case, while the latter doesn't work well with C++ and I'm still investigating building it from the latest source.

Along these lines, I have investigated what the `dwz` tool [announced here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-04/msg00686.html) is doing to see if can be tweaked to borrow DIEs from an already existing (but stale) debug info file.  Any tips, documents, or pseudo-code in this direction would also be helpful.

Comment: How about using `-gsplit-dwarf` when compiling?

Comment: @user657267 From this link https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission, I still don't understand how having a separate dwarf file is going to help me diff easier?  I haven't researched the format of a dwarf file yet.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but having debug symbols in a separate file means you can just `diff` the two and distribute a patch.

Comment: `diff` really only works very well on text files-- I don't know yet that the .dwo files are `diff` friendly.  `split` can already separate the debug symbols into a separate file, that file just isn't `diff` friendly.

Comment: How well does `gzip` compress the file?

Comment: @Mark I can try `gzip`-- `bzip2` cuts the size by about 1/2, but unfortunately this is still a couple 100 MB.

Answer (score 1):

> In the normal development cycle I have to copy my several 100 MB binary (with debug symbols) over a very slow link over and over again.

Have to?

Your use case *screams* for using remote debugging, where all the debug info stays on the development system, and you *only* have to transfer the stripped binary to the target.

Info about using `gdbserver` is [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html).

If, for some reason you can't use `gdbserver` ...

> From this link gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission, I still don't understand how having a separate dwarf file is going to help me diff easier?

With separate debug info, in a usual compile/debug cycle, you'll be recompiling only a few files, and relinking the final binary.

That means that most of the `.o` and `.dwo` files will not be rebuilt, which means that you wouldn't have to re-send the unchanged `.dwo` files to the target, i.e. you get *incremental* debug info updates "for free".

Update:

> We also use the debug symbols to generate backtraces for exceptions in the running application. I think having the symbols locally is the only option for that use case.

Only if you insist on the backtrace being fully-symbolized with file/line info.

The *usual* way to deal with this is to have the backtrace contain only `PC` values (and perhaps function names), and use `addr2line` on the development system to recover file/line info when necessary.

Comment: We also use the debug symbols to generate backtraces for exceptions in the running application.  I think having the symbols locally is the only option for that use case.  As for the `.dwo` files, I wasn't realizing that there were many of them, in which case I can understand the benefit.  I still feel like there should be a tool to encode the symbols as integers and copy mappings or something..